# Where is the source of this Heisenbug for a Wordpress twentysixteen child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, theming

I am working on a child theme to Wordpress's twentysixteen theme, and one boilerplate move is to restore text-decoration underline to links.

For some links, as below, this results in two lines, not one, under the text, unless you hover over. If you hover over the link one of them goes away. (In other words, I may have a Heisenbug that defeats the usual song and dance for when CSS is a bit off.)

Needless to say, this somewhat complicates the process of using Chrome's Inspect Element feature. My working hypothesis is that there is a border-bottom or the like in twentysixteen, possibly due to an accessibility concern that some people handle descenders more easily if an underline is lower than browser defaults. However, after inspection via Chrome's Inspect Element, and some effort to wade through the basic twentysixteen's style.css, I am not entirely sure what the correct way is to say, "I want all links underlined, and no double underlining."

If I want to keep `text-decoration: underline` for links, how can I remove the additional underline?

[image: Picture of double underlining]

Comment: Is there a bottom border applied to the links?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)